behaviour of inline-block element with float elements


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.uj {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: inline-block;
}

.qw {
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="qw" alt="" height="22px">
<span>other text</span>

<div class="uj">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique pariatur t a quam eligendi dolores earum in officia qui maiores, doloremque repellendus dolore a chitecto, quaerat assumenda odio eaque! Saepe, et.</div>

<img src="https://placehold.co/400" alt="" height="22px">



when we remove the inline block from uj class, lorem ipsum appears on the left side of the image while when we keep it, it appears from the new line after the image. Though span text always appears on the left side of the image. Can you tell me why?

your inline-block element contains a lot of text so it will try to get as much space as possible so it won't sit next to the float

@TemaniAfif "so it won't sit next to the float" can you better explain this?

start with a small text content and keep adding more and see what happens then you will understand

If an inline-block element’s width is not specified, the element box will shrink to fit its content. Here, you have a lot of text, and no specified width, so it will take the full width of the container, which is 100% of the container. Below, in the snippet, I have set the size of the container to 50%. See how the inline-block behaves.
When the text is larger than what can be fitted in the remaining space in the container (the remaining space at the right side of the image), it flows below the image, as the available space is less than the block-inline's width (which is 100% in this case, as there is a lot of text inside the block).
Below it, I have kept a minimum of text that can be easily fitted in the remaining space on the right side of the image in the container. As the available space is enough for the text to be fitted, it just sits in that space and doesn't flow below the image.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    
    .cont {
      width: 50%
    }
    
    .uj {
      background-color: aqua;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .qw {
      height: 200px;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='cont'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="qw" alt="" height="22px">
    <span>other text</span>

    <div class="uj">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique pariatur t a quam eligendi dolores earum in officia qui maiores, doloremque repellendus dolore a chitecto, quaerat assumenda odio eaque! Saepe, et.</div>

    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" alt="" height="22px">
  </div>
<p> Less text </p> 
  <div class='cont'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="qw" alt="" height="22px">
    <span>other text</span>

    <div class="uj">Lorem ipsum </div>

    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" alt="" height="22px">
  </div>
</body>

</html>




i dont understand when width is 50% why does it go to the bottom instead of showing to the left of image. Also i dont understand in my code when it cant achieve 100% width why paragraph goes to bottom?

@Ujjawal The 50% width is applied to the container and not the inline-block. Add width: 50%; to the class .uj in 'your' code (not mine) and see what happens. The inline-block will sit at the right side of the image and will not flow below.
